# Derivative of $(x+|x|)\sqrt{|x|}$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Calculating the derivative is easy, but online math engines state that
$$f(x) = (x+|x|)\sqrt{|x|}$$
is differentiable at $x_0=0$ as well. The derivative is
$$f'(x) = \frac{3x^2+3x\left|x\right|}{2\left|x\right|\sqrt{\left|x\right|}}$$

Do I need to use the limit definition manually to prove for differentiability at $x_0 = 0$? Note that $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: If the computation for the formula for $f'(x)$ was done applying the rules of differentiation with respect to the arithmetic operations, then in particular they were applied in the places where$\sqrt{|x|}$ is differentiable. In particular, that excludes $x=0$. Therefore, the case $x=0$ must be studied on its own.

Comment: You obtain that $f'(0)=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{(x+|x|)\sqrt{|x|}}{x}$, which is equal to $0$, since $\frac{x+|x|}{x}$ is bounded and $\sqrt{|x|}\to0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function is $2x^{3/2}$ for $x\ge0$ and $0$ for $x<0$, so its derivative is $3x^{1/2}$ for $x>0$ and $0$ for $x<0$. Let's be careful with the derivative at $0$. The left-hand limit is $0$; the right-hand limit is $\lim_{x\to0^+}2x^{1/2}=0$.

Comment: Very concise. Thank you, I should think the problem through before I blindly calculate a derivative.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to use the limit definition manually, and check the right and left derivatives separately. So with $x>0$, you have $f(x)=2x^{3/2}$, so that the right-hand-side derivative at zero is zero, and with $x<0$, you have $f(x)=0$ so the left-hand-side derivative at zero is also zero. Therefore, $f(x)$ is differentiable at zero and the derivative there is equal to zero.

- My initial answer was wrong, as I mistakenly thought that the function was $(x+|x|)/\sqrt{|x|}$.

Comment: Interesting, so is this basically wrong? https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=derivative+%28x%2B%7Cx%7C%29sqrt%28%7Cx%7C%29

Comment: I think you missed out the $x$.

Answer (score 0):

For $x<0$, we have that $f(x)=0$. For $x>0$, we have that $f(x)=2x\sqrt{x}$, and $f(0)=0$. The derivative from left is trivially $0$, and from right it's
$\lim_{x \to 0^+}\frac{2x\sqrt{x}}{x}=0$.
So it's differentiable at 0.